# Trouble creating modularized, abstract functions to update mongodb (mongoose) database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, function, callback

I am trying to create a modular and abstract group of functions to persist data to my Mongodb (Mongoose) database using Node JS like so:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
mongoose.connect('xyz123blahblahblah')
const db       = mongoose.connection
const Schema   = mongoose.Schema
const ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId

var doc
var docInstance

// Connect to the database.
function connect() {
    console.log('Establishing a connection.')
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error:'))

    db.once('open', function() {
      console.log('Connection established.')
      updateCollection() 
    })
}

function updateCollection(schemaName, schemaObject, schemaProperties) {
    doc         = mongoose.model(schemaName, schemaObject)
    docInstance = new doc(schemaProperties)
}

function save() {
    console.log('Saving document to the collection.')
    docInstance.save(function (err, docInstance) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err) } 
        else { console.log('Document was succesfully added.') }
    })
}
```

Now the idea is, later on, I can export these functions and call them sequentially like so:

```
// Define the Collection model.
const User = new Schema( { name: String, email: String, id: ObjectId} )

connect()
updateCollection('users', User, { name: 'Testy McTest', email: 'test@test.co' })
save()
```

It doesn't make sense to me to pass the parameters for the updateCollection() function via the connect() function as these are essentially responsible for two different things more or less, but my updateCollection() function needs to be called INSIDE of my connect() function.

An ideal solution for me would be having the ability to do the following:

```
// Define the Collection model.
const User = new Schema( { name: String, email: String, id: ObjectId} 

connect(updateCollection('users', User, { name: 'Testy McTest', email: 'test@test.co' }))
save()
```

I'm a bit lost now on how to proceed. Would it be possible to construct my  connect() and updateCollection() functions in this way to ensure a separation of concerns? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var doc
var docInstance

function connect(updateCollection) {
    console.log('Establishing a connection...')
    db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'Connection error:'))

    db.once('open', function() {
      console.log('Connection established.')
      updateCollection 
    })
}

function updateCollection(schemaName, schemaObject, schemaProperties) {
    doc = mongoose.model(schemaName, schemaObject)
    for (let i = 0; i < schemaProperties.length; i++) { 
        docInstance = new doc(schemaProperties[i])
        save() 
    }
    /*  
        TODO:
        The connection is currently being closed BEFORE
        all collections have been added to the database.
        We need a way to prevent the connection from closing
        until all Update operations are complete.
    */
    // console.log('Closing the connection.')
    // mongoose.connection.close()
}

function save() {
    console.log('Saving document to the collection...')
    docInstance.save(function (err, docInstance) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err) } 
        else { console.log('Document was succesfully added.') }
    })
}
```

After spending a good deal of time on this I believe I've found the optimal solution. Callbacks. I can now call my connect() function like so:

```
connect(updateCollection( 'users', User, [{ name: 'Testy 5', email: 'test5@test.co' }, { name: 'Testy 6', email: 'test6@test.co' }] ))
```

Furthermore, I have updated my updateCollection() method to take X number of objects in an array of objects to update the rows in the db :)